# parallax jquery infinite(360) scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

I need to create a site with infinite(360) scrolling.  here's the [example](http://unfold.no/).  I have checked a couple of plugins like superscrollorama and also [scrollpath](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)  but don't quite grasp of how to achieve it.  Not looking for the complete answer, just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You could check out *Skrollr* -  **[demo](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)** and the project on **[Github](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)**

Comment: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/